# Running Multiple Turtles Speed on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am trying to build a nuclear reactor model in python (not something very percise, just for the sake of learning and have fun). I am following this [model](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/ReactorTopDown).

So far, I've built the basic main frame. The fuel, neutrons, and essentially the basic stuff like the board and borders. As you may know, when a neutron hits the appropriate element, it's able to break that element into two, and produce one (or a few) more neutrons. I have applied the same concept in my code, when a neutron hits a fuel particle, another neutron will be generated. The problem I am facing now though is the fact that when I get to a certain number of neutrons on screen, the simulation begins to slow down until its not bearable to watch.

I've been looking through my code, trying to make it more efficient, but I couldn't find something specific or special that would cause this.

My code:

```
import turtle
from random import randint


class Reactor:

    def __init__(self, spendfuel, board, startNeut, iterr, percent_fuel):

        self.fuel = []
        self.fuel_t = self.newParticle('red','square',0,0)

        self.spendfuel = spendfuel

        turtle.setup(board[0]+200,board[1]+200), turtle.title("Reactor Top Down Reaction Model")

        self.fuel,self.neutrons = self.setup(percent_fuel,board[0]//2,board[1]//2,1)

        for i in range(iterr):
            self.react(board[0]//2, board[1]//2)
            if (len(self.neutrons) == 0):
                return
            turtle.update()


    def setup(self, percent_fuel, x_length, y_length, neutronsNum):
        turtle.bgcolor("black"), turtle.tracer(0,0)

        for row in range(-x_length,x_length,4):
            for column in range(y_length,-y_length,-4):
                if (percent_fuel > randint(0,100)):
                    self.fuel_t.goto(row,column)
                    s_id = self.fuel_t.stamp()
                    s_pos = self.fuel_t.pos()
                    self.fuel.append([s_id,s_pos])

        self.fuel_t.color('sienna')
        self.neutrons = [ self.newParticle('yellow','circle',randint(-x_length,x_length),randint(-y_length,y_length)) for neutron in range(neutronsNum)]
        turtle.update()

        return self.fuel,self.neutrons

    def react(self, x_length, y_length):
        self.power = 0
        for index,neutron in enumerate(self.neutrons):

            x_pos = int(neutron.xcor())
            y_pos = int(neutron.ycor())
            inside_border = False

            if ((-x_length <= x_pos) and (x_pos <= x_length) and (-y_length <= y_pos) and (y_pos <= y_length)):
                inside_border = True

                neutron.fd(2)

                start = 0
                if (x_pos <= 0 and y_pos >= 0): #Start the search for a nearby uranim from the current neutron's quad.
                    start = 0
                elif (x_pos < 0 and y_pos < 0):
                    start = len(self.fuel) // 4
                elif (x_pos > 0 and y_pos > 0):
                    start = len(self.fuel) // 2
                else:
                    start = int(len(self.fuel) // 1.3333)

                for i in range(start,len(self.fuel)-1):
                    if (neutron.distance(self.fuel[i][1]) <= 1):
                        self.fission(neutron,i,self.neutrons)
                        break

            if not(inside_border):
                self.neutrons.remove(neutron)
                neutron.ht()


    def fission(self, neutron, index, neutrons):
        neutron.rt(randint(0,360))
        if (self.spendfuel):
            self.fuel_t.goto(self.fuel[index][1])
            self.fuel_t.stamp()
            self.fuel.pop(index)

        neutrons.append(self.newParticle('yellow','circle',neutron.xcor(),neutron.ycor()))
        neutrons[-1].rt(randint(0,360))

    def newParticle(self, color, shape, row, column):
        t = turtle.Pen() #New turltle type object
        t.pu(), t.speed(10), t.ht(), t.color(color), t.shape(shape), t.shapesize(0.125,0.125,0.125)
        t.goto(row,column), t.st()
        return t





if __name__ == "__main__":

    g = Reactor(False, [400,400], 1, 300, 10)
```

I would appreciate any help sorting this out, and making my model run faster. It's also important to say that the neutrons, unlike the fuel particles which are `turtle.stamp()`, are turtle objects. Neutrons are represented by the color -- yellow -- while the fuel particles are represented by the color -- red--

Comment: This is way too much code. Also, it doesn't run as-is. And if you fix the obvious indentation errors, it does run, but immediately quits, so it still doesn't demonstrate the problem you're asking about. Please read [mcve] in the help.

Comment: I fixed the indentation and put an older version of my code with always works, the version I had before a some trouble with spawning the first neutron, sorry about that. @abarnert

Comment: It's still way too much code. You need to figure out how to reduce this down to just the essentials needed to demonstrate the problem. Without that, I could make some guesses (e.g., are you fissioning the neutron and then checking the new neutrons before removing the fuel?), but they're just wild guesses without a lot of debugging effort to narrow it down.

Comment: @OmerHen You *do* have a (nested) loop outside of the "self.fission" line.  It's extremely likely that the if-condition is evaluating to true more often than you expect.  I put a print statement in there, and got a lot of print-outs.  Tweak your magic number from 2 to something else.

Comment: I narrowed the code down. In the model that I follow (you can find the link in the post) the default settings was that when the neutrons hit the fuel, they do not waste it they just split and the fuel stays intact. So I tried to follow that same procedure. @abarnert

Comment: That was just a wild guess, but… if you fission a neutron that comes near fuel into two neutrons, both of which are near the same fuel, and you don't do anything to guarantee that they start off far enough away to avoid fissioning on the next time tick, wouldn't that frequently give you a whole burst of fission events where you were expecting one? (Again, I haven't read over your code, or the model, so there may be a reason that can't happen—if you're not sure, add some code that prints out new neutrons' ids as they get created and as they fission and see if it happens.)

Comment: Thanks! @ScottMermelstein I changed it to 1 and changed the `continue` state into a `break`, and the problem of the clusters was solved. The problem that it is still very slow still exists though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but after making the fix that Scott M. suggested the problem with the clusters was fixed. My model is still very slow when there are a lot of neutrons though. @abarnert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This call is one of your bottlenecks (perhaps 2/3 of your time):

```
if (neutron.distance(self.fuel[i][1]) <= 1):
```

it happens hundreds of thousands of times (possibly millions with the right parameters) and at it's heart it's doing expensive arithmetic:

```
(self[0]**2 + self[1]**2)**0.5
```

when it calls `abs()` on the result of the Vec2D subtraction.  (It's even testing if `self.fuel[i][1]` is a Vec2D when you know it is.)  Since our target is `<= 1`, we may not need exponentiation and square roots, we might be able to get away with a less expensive approximation like:

```
distance = self.fuel[i][1] - neutron.position()  # returns a Vec2D

if abs(distance[0]) + abs(distance[1]) <= 1:
```

Reducing this bottleneck to something more like 1/3 of your time.  (I.e. test a bounding square rather than test a bounding circle.)

> it is still relatively slow and I'd like it to be faster

We'll use a traditional approach to this problem, trade off space for speed by turning `self.fuel` into a sparse matrix instead of a list.  That way we eliminate the search altogether and just check if the current position is sitting on a fuel rod:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import randint

BORDER = 100
MAGNIFICATION = 4
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

class Reactor:

    def __init__(self, spendfuel, board, startNeut, iterations, percent_fuel):

        width, height = board

        screen = Screen()
        screen.setup(width + BORDER * 2, height + BORDER * 2)
        screen.setworldcoordinates(-BORDER // MAGNIFICATION, -BORDER // MAGNIFICATION, (width + BORDER) // MAGNIFICATION, (height + BORDER) // MAGNIFICATION)
        screen.title("Reactor Top Down Reaction Model")
        screen.bgcolor("black")
        screen.tracer(0)

        scaled_width, scaled_height = width // MAGNIFICATION, height // MAGNIFICATION

        self.fuel = [[None for x in range(scaled_width)] for y in range(scaled_height)]
        self.fuel_t = self.newParticle('red', 'square', (0, 0))
        self.spendfuel = spendfuel

        self.neutrons = []

        self.setup(percent_fuel, scaled_width, scaled_height, startNeut)

        screen.update()

        for _ in range(iterations):
            self.react(scaled_width, scaled_height)
            if not self.neutrons:
                break
            screen.update()

        screen.exitonclick()

    def setup(self, percent_fuel, x_length, y_length, neutronsNum):

        for row in range(x_length):
            for column in range(y_length):
                if percent_fuel > randint(0, 100):
                    self.fuel_t.goto(row, column)
                    self.fuel[row][column] = self.fuel_t.stamp()

        self.fuel_t.color('sienna')  # spent fuel color

        for _ in range(neutronsNum):
            neutron = self.newParticle('yellow', 'circle', (randint(0, x_length), randint(0, y_length)))
            neutron.setheading(neutron.towards((0, 0)))
            self.neutrons.append(neutron)

    def react(self, x_length, y_length):

        neutrons = self.neutrons[:]

        for neutron in neutrons:
            x_pos, y_pos = neutron.position()

            if 0 <= x_pos < x_length and 0 <= y_pos < y_length:

                x_int, y_int = int(x_pos), int(y_pos)

                if self.fuel[x_int][y_int]:
                    self.fission(neutron, x_int, y_int)

                neutron.forward(1)
            else:
                self.neutrons.remove(neutron)
                neutron.hideturtle()

    def fission(self, neutron, x, y):

        if self.spendfuel:
            self.fuel_t.clearstamp(self.fuel[x][y])
            self.fuel_t.goto(x, y)
            self.fuel_t.stamp()
            self.fuel[x][y] = None

        neutron.right(randint(0, 360))
        new_neutron = neutron.clone()
        new_neutron.right(randint(0, 360))
        self.neutrons.append(new_neutron)

    @staticmethod
    def newParticle(color, shape, position):

        particle = Turtle(shape, visible=False)
        particle.shapesize(MAGNIFICATION / CURSOR_SIZE, outline=0)
        particle.speed('fastest')
        particle.color(color)

        particle.penup()
        particle.goto(position)
        particle.showturtle()

        return particle

if __name__ == "__main__":

    g = Reactor(True, [400, 400], 1, 400, 5)
```

I've made a number of other modifications to your code for both speed and style.  I've also formalized your magnification which was somewhat haphazard in your original code.

Comment: Thanks! I've made the changes you suggested and the simulation does seem to move faster. Though it is still relatively slow and I'd like it to be faster. I've been doing some checks, and like you said, the `if (neutron.distance(self.fuel[i][1]) <= 1):` statement is called a lot of times, that is because it is in the nested for loop that goes over the `self.fuel` array for each neutron. Do you have an idea maybe how can I find nearby fuel without having to go over the array and checking each fuel particle individually? @cdlane

Comment: @OmerHen, I've augmented my answer with a rework of your code that removes the fuel search by making it a sparse matrix instead of a list.  Along with lots of other changes for you to consider.

Comment: Thank you, this was the exact solution I was looking for. The sparse matrix does seem to handle this situation in a faster more efficient way. I'm sorry for the poor coding style, this was one of my first few versions of the code, as I wanted to post something short that cuts right into the problem. Thanks again! @cdlane